# Slurm: Handling nodes that fail to POWER_UP in a cloud scheduling system

Tags: slurm

## Issue

### Current behavior and problem description

When a node fails to `POWER_UP`, it is marked `DOWN`. While this is a great idea in general, this is not useful when working with `CLOUD` nodes, because said `CLOUD` node is likely to be started on a different machine and therefore to `POWER_UP` without issues. But since the node is marked as down, that cloud resource is no longer used and never started again until freed manually.

### Wanted behavior

Ideally slurm would not mark the node as `DOWN`, but just attempt to start another. If that's not possible, automatically resuming `DOWN` nodes would also be an option.

### Question

How can I prevent slurm from marking nodes that fail to `POWER_UP` as `DOWN` or make slurm restore `DOWN` nodes automatically to prevent slurm from forgetting cloud resources?

## Attempts and Thoughts

### ReturnToService

I tried solving this using [`ReturnToService`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_ReturnToService) but that didn't seem to solve my issue, since, if I understand it correctly, that will only accept slurm nodes starting up by themselves or manually not taking them in consideration when scheduling jobs until they've been started.

### ResumeFailedProgram

I considered using [`ResumeFailedProgram`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_ResumeFailProgram), but it sounds odd that you have to write yourself a script for returning your nodes to service.

### SlurmctldParameters=idle_on_node_suspend

While this is great and definitely helpful, it doesn't solve the issue at hand since a node that failed during power up, is not suspended.

## Additional Information

In the `POWER_UP` script I am terminating the server if the setup fails for any reason and return an exit code unequal to 0.

In our [Cloud Scheduling](https://slurm.schedmd.com/elastic_computing.html) instances are created once they are needed and deleted once they are no longer deleted. This means that slurm stores that a node is `DOWN` while no real instance behind it exists anymore. If that node wouldn't be marked `DOWN` and a job would be scheduled towards it at a later time, it would simply start an instance and run on that new instance. I am just stating this to be maximum explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResumeFailProgram` is exactly the way to solve it. You're hitting the mismatch between slurm's view of "nodes" and what is actually providing these in a cloud environment. In this situation probably the ResumeFailProgram should use the cloud APIs to check whether it actually was likely to be a transient provisioning failure (e.g. some errors like out-of-quota, lost networking might need intervention rather than retrying, and staying DOWN is probably the right thing to do), then if so, just run `scontrol update nodename=whatever state=resume` to make that "node" (really, just a nodename here) eligible for powersaving to try and "resume" it again.

Comment: Indeed. This is what we ended up using. I forgot to post it as an answer here. Thank you very much!